# Get HTML from another domain

Tags: php, html, curl

I want to fetch a certain link at every 30 seconds interval and parse it's code in my program. Is there a way to do this?

I need to obtain certain things found in it's code that always change at fixed intervals.

I've tried using an `iframe` and getting it's innerHTML but that doesn't work also php's `file_get_contents()` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can use `file_get_contents()` or cURL.  If `file_get_contents()` isn't working, then you probably need to specify a `referer` or `User-Agent` header.  Also be absolutely sure you have permission to do what you are doing.

Comment: Does the site you're connecting to have an API you can use? You should probably speak to the site's owner and see if there's some easier way to get to the content

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.******.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\******\test2.php on line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try using this?
http://davidwalsh.name/download-urls-content-php-curl

The code

```
 /* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Then call with

```
$returned_content = get_data('http://davidwalsh.name');
```

(Credit to DAVID WALSH)

Comment: Great. if it works, please tick and up vote my answer :D good luck

Comment: Answers that are solely links will become useless once the link disappears. It's best to also summarize the contents here.

Comment: @webbiedave That's true.. I just did a quick Google for user783476. Not a PHP Dev myself

Comment: well... it worked when i used your link(davidwalsh.name) but it didn't do anything when i wanted to connect to mine (https://www.neobux.com)

Comment: thing is... when i write https://.... in the url, nothing happens.. i just get a blank page with no errors.

Comment: on the other hand, when i use http://... in the url, i get a timeout error after 30 seconds because the maximum execution time is exceeded

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried using an iframe and getting it's innerHTML but that doesn't work

That would run into the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

> also php's file_get_contents() doesn't work

If the data is in the HTML itself, it should do (unless the function has been disabled on your install of PHP).

It is possible that the site you are trying to scrape from has taken steps to block abusive crawlers.

(And hitting a third party site and scraping their HTML every 30 seconds sounds pretty abusive).

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_content` does not work because it has been disabled on your server (probably for security reasons). You could either enable it, or use cURL.

Comment: Well, maybe the website detects you are using no browser but a script to download its data and does not want you to do this. Try setting some additional frequently used headers…

Comment: hmm... if I use some headers i could trick the website into thinking that a browser is trying to access it's data?

Comment: Exactly. This is not recommended for obvious reasons, though.